# mvc, two project connecting to the one database, updating table with project-A it's not effecting in project-B

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

### -MVC5, Project-A & Project-B are connecting to one database

here i have created interfaces and repositories to manage objects(Database First ) therefore create a new connection string

Connection for the repository and default(this manage the default asp.net Identity) is bellow:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=DATABASEName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="RepoConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MSSQLSERVER01;initial catalog=DATABASEName;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

those connection are located in both projects web.config

now when i want to change a record in Project-A and same record i want to return from the Project-B

- On insert i am able to return the record from Project-B
- On Update with Project-A its return what was inserted int Project-B and the new change is not effecting with project-B which was updated by Project-A

but when i rebuild the project i am able to see the changes, so do i need to have any cache clear method or do i need to add any code in

change by project-A with conneciton string **Repo**

```
 TableName tb = db.TableName.Single(a => a.Id==Id);
          tb.StatusId= 1;
          db.Entry(tb).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
```

returning by project-B with connection string **Repo**

```
var data = db.TableName.Single(a=>a.Id==Id);
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Add a bit of how you are changing the entity in both projects

Comment: updated, thank you @NitinSingh

Comment: Are the changes reflected in the database but not the projects? If so, maybe you need to dispose and re-create your dbContexts. Are you using `using` statements to manage your dbContexts?